# A Pythonic way to "query" a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I have a nested dictionary which contains the data about books:

- UID
- Condition
- Price

Here is the definition:

```
books = {
    'uid1':
        {'price': '100',
        'condition': 'good'},
    'uid2':
        {'price': '80',
        'condition': 'fair'},
    'uid3':
        {'price': '150',
        'condition': 'excellent'},
    'uid4':
        {'price': '70',
        'condition': 'fair'},
    'uid5':
        {'price': '180',
        'condition': 'excellent'},
    'uid6':
        {'price': '60',
        'condition': 'fair'}
    }
```

I need to get average prices, grouped by condition. So, the intended result is:

```
{'fair': 70, 'good': 100, 'excellent': 165}
```

What is the most Pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to answer this question using Pandas Library.

```
import pandas as pd
books = {
    'uid1':
        {'price': '100',
        'condition': 'good'},
    'uid2':
        {'price': '80',
        'condition': 'fair'},
    'uid3':
        {'price': '150',
        'condition': 'excellent'},
    'uid4':
        {'price': '70',
        'condition': 'fair'},
    'uid5':
        {'price': '180',
        'condition': 'excellent'},
    'uid6':
        {'price': '60',
        'condition': 'fair'}
   }
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(books, orient='index')
data['price'] = data[['price']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
data.groupby(['condition'])['price'].mean()
```

**Output:**

```
condition
excellent    165
fair          70
good         100
```

Comment: pandas seems like the most natural solution to this. Whenever I see one of the (relatively rare) situations where R is more elegant than Python for a certain type of problem, there is usually a pandas solution lurking around.

Comment: Yeah, pandas might be really useful. I have many more fields and potential queries for this dictionary, so creating and querying a dataframe sounds really promising.

Answer (score 3):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Demo:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in books.items():
    res[v['condition']].append(int(v['price'])) 

print({k: sum(v)/len(v) for k, v in res.items() })
```

**Output:**

```
{'good': 100, 'fair': 70, 'excellent': 165}
```

Comment: Oh, `defaultdict` nails it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach:

```
from statistics import mean
result = {condition: mean(float(book['price']) for book in books.values() if book['condition'] == condition) for condition in ('fair','good','excellent')}

#result = {'fair': 70.0, 'good': 100.0, 'excellent': 165.0}
```

Comment: This assumes you already know the list of possible conditions. What if you don't?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Then you have to do something much less elegant (if you want to use a direct dictionary comprehension). This limitation is one of the reasons I upvoted the `pandas` answer and was glad to see that it was accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you need `defaultdict` except for not using `Try Except` -

```
for k, v in books.items():
    try:
        avg[v['condition']].append(int(v['price']))
    except KeyError:
        avg[v['condition']] = [int(v['price'])]
avg = {k: sum(v)/len(v) for k, v in avg.items()}
```